# SED: how to find only even numbers in a given file using sed

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

I am new to bash and having a tough time figuring this out.

Using `sed`, could anyone help me in finding only even numbers in a given file?

I figured out how to find all numbers starting from [0,2,4,6,8] using this:

```
sed -n 's/^[0-9]*[02468] /&/w even' <file
```

But this doesn't guarantee that the number is even for sure.

I am having trouble in finding if the matched number ends with either [0,2,4,6,8] for it to be even for sure.

So can any one help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex looks a bit weird and I am not sure what you want to do, but this should help:

```
sed -r -n 's/^[0-9]*?[02468] /even/g'
```

`-r` to enable extended regex, `*?` to make it non-greedy, and `/g` to perform replacement globally for all lines in file.

Comment: Firstly I think you may be confusing `perl` with `sed` as far as I know `sed` has no such `non-greedy` operator. Secondly as you have invoked `-n` nothing will be printed as the `p` flag is not present in the substitute command. Lastly, it is unclear but I believe the @user445687 wanted those lines beginning with an even number or the number itself, to be written to a file called `even`.

Answer (score 1):

Your command should work fine assuming that there is a space after all even numbers and that they are all at the beginning of the lines:

```
$ echo 'foo 
1231 
2220 
1254 ' | sed -n '/[0-9]*[02468] /p'
2220 
1254
```

Also note that, as you don't actually do a substitution, you don't need the `s` command. Use an address (pattern) specifier and `w` command (like I did above with the `p` command).

To make sure that the even digit is the last, but is not necessarily followed by a space, you can do something like

```
$ echo 'foo
1231
2220
1254 ' | sed -n '/[0-9]*[02468]\($\|[^0-9]\)/p'
2220
1254
```

Actually, your case looks more like a use case for `grep`, not `sed`, because you do filtering rather than editing. Everything becomes easier with `GNU grep`, as you can do

```
$ echo 'foo
1231
2220
1254 ' | grep -P '\d*[02468](?!\d)'
2220
1254
```

Just append `> even` to the command to make it write to the file `even`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
498
57
12345678
$ awk '$0%2' file
1
3
57
$ awk '!($0%2)' file
2
498
12345678
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you find the numbers ending with [02468] ?